# SimMechanics - Choose point of application of torque

Tags: matlab, simulink, simmechanics

I have a CAD model of a bar `25cm x 5cm x 2cm` imported into SimMechanics.
On one of the sides, I have a small "hole", around which I have to apply a certain torque, to make the bar spin.
I have applied said torque through a revolute joint, but the axis of rotation is assumed by SimMechanics to be one of the edges, giving a "lopsided" rotation.
How can I shift the position of the torque to this specific point on the bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, the way I solved it was to add a Rigid Transform "after" the revolute joint.
What happened was that adding the Rigid Transform after the revolute joint essentially "shifted" the bar to the imaginary axis of rotation of the revolute joint, which was what I was looking for.